# auto filling in phone number field off of copy paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm somewhat new to webdev, and html as a whole, still learning. I have a basic phone number form with 3 fields, and have been trying to make it so you can copy the number right into the fields. Something that would check if the previous field was filled and then fill the next box with the next part of the number?
Thanks for any help you can provide.
(here's the html)

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Phone Input Test</title>
<script type= javascript>
var isNN = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")!=-1);
function autoTab(input,len, e) {
  var keyCode = (isNN) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  var filter = (isNN) ? [0,8,9] : [0,8,9,16,17,18,37,38,39,40,46];
  if(input.value.length >= len && !containsElement(filter,keyCode)) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, len);
    input.form[(getIndex(input)+1) % input.form.length].focus();
  }

function containsElement(arr, ele) {
  var found = false, index = 0;
  while(!found && index < arr.length)
    if(arr[index] == ele)
      found = true;
    else
      enter code here
    index++;
  return found;
}

function getIndex(input) {
  var index = -1, i = 0, found = false;
  while (i < input.form.length && index == -1)
    if (input.form[i] == input)
      index = i;
    else 
      i++;
  return index;
}
return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>
<form action="phonetest.html" method="post">
<input type="text" name="dest_ac" size=3 onKeyUp="return autoTab(this, 3, event);" maxlength=3>
<input type="text" name="dest_niu" size=3 onKeyUp="return autoTab(this, 3, event);" maxlength=3>
<input type="text" name="dest_st" size=4 maxlength=4>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly , you want it to autofill after entering 2-3 digits? If so not sure if it's possible without a database or some type web framework like angular. Even if you use a web framework I don't think there is a way without a database.

Comment: @JasmitTarang close. I meant copying a phone number into the first field, and it taking the parts of the numbers and put them in the apropriate field. Like 303 456 4854, 303 in the first box, 456 in the 2nd box, etc...

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do that, but anyway, slice the numbers by 3 twice, you are left with 4 numbers. Keep the numbers in variables and then clear the inputs then assign the inputs with the values you have in the variables. If using jQuery it would be ```$("dest_ac").value(variable_first_three)```

Comment: thanks for the advice man! I will certainly try that out and tweak it to my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $(function () {

            var $inputs = $(".def-txt-input");
            var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

            $inputs.on("input.fromManual", function () {
                if (!intRegex.test($(this).val())) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });


            $inputs.on("paste", function () {
                $inputs.attr("maxlength", 15);
                var $this = $(this);
                var originalValue = $this.val();
                
    
                $this.val("");
    
                $this.one("input.fromPaste", function () {

                    var values = $(this).val().match(/.{1,1}/g);
                    $("#txtBox1").val("");
                    $inputs.attr("maxlength", 5);
                    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        if ($("#txtBox1").val().length < 5) {
                            this.value = this.value.toString() + values[i];
                        }
                        else if ($("#txtBox2").val().length < 5) {
                            $("#txtBox2").val( $("#txtBox2").val().toString() + values[i]);
                        }
                        else if ($("#txtBox3").val().length < 5){
                            $("#txtBox3").val($("#txtBox3").val().toString() + values[i]);
                        }
                    }

                });

               
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <input id="txtBox1" type="text" class="def-txt-input" maxlength="5">
        <input id="txtBox2" type="text" class="def-txt-input" maxlength="5">
        <input id="txtBox3" type="text" class="def-txt-input" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemingly solved my problem. I know very little about jquery, so i gladly appreciate your help